# how to get jquery ajax form submit process time so i can disable to use the form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$('#fmemail').form('submit',{
                    url: uri,
                    onSubmit: function(){
                        //return $(this).form('validate');
                    },
                    success: function(result){
                        var result = eval('('+result+')');
                        if (result.success){
                            $('#et').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                        } else {
                            $.messager.show({
                                title: 'Error',
                                msg: result.msg
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: this is the form submition code it working fine but i need to know while the submitted data is processing specially when i use image upload it take bit time so how can i know the processing status.and i can disable the form to use other thing so it can process finish then user can use it

Comment: Check out jQuery's [ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

Comment: sorry i got the final answer:success: function(result){
      var result = eval('('+result+')');
      if (result.success){
       //$('#dgsp').datagrid('reload');
       $.messager.show({
        title: 'Success',
        msg: result.message
       });

      } else {
       $.messager.show({
        title: 'Error',
        msg: result.msg
       });
      }
     }

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fmemail').submit(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: uri
        data: $('#fmemail').serialize(),
        success: function(result){
            ...
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should register with the submit function and prevent the default activity (i.e. submission). Then you are able to submit and asynchronous call and use *beforeSend* hook to do some locking activity in your code.

```
var form = $('#fmemail');
$(form).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
       url: $(form).attr('action'),
       data: $(form).serialize(),
       beforeSend: lockingMethod(), // do your magic here
       success: function(result){
                    var result = eval('('+result+')');
                    if (result.success){
                        $('#et').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                    } else {
                        $.messager.show({
                            title: 'Error',
                            msg: result.msg
                        });
                    }
                }

    });
    reurn false;
}
```